# JiBX unmarshal is failing in Jboss 7.3 version

Tags: jboss, unmarshalling, jibx

Getting the following error while starting the server after Jboss upgrade from 4.2 to 7.3. There are no changes made to the code.

BeanCreationException | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageDispatcher' defined in class path resource [context/runtime.core.context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.xml.model.action.FunctionAction.JiBX_core_bindings_unmarshal_2_0(Lorg/jibx/runtime/impl/UnmarshallingContext;)Lcom/test/xml/model/action/FunctionAction;

JiBX version - 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading JiBX to a more recent version. The current version is 1.4.2. Find the documentation at jibx.org. The latest code is in Maven Central.